# Calling environment in Github actions

Tags: github, github-actions

I need to work with a script parameter in a Github Workflow like the following, but I get an error like the following. I could not call it.

```
Run bash ./test.sh -x "***"
  bash ./test.sh -x "***"
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
./test.sh: illegal option -- x
```

```
- run: bash ./test.sh -x "${{ vars.TEST_VARIABLE }}"
```

I tried all variables.

Comment: it should be `env` not `vars`, so  run: `bash ./test.sh -x "${{ env.TEST_VARIABLE }}"`

Comment: Does `test.sh` script understand and is able to handle the `-x` command line option i.e. `illegal option -- x`? Also, update your question with the relevant workflow steps along with the details of how your set `TEST_VARIABLE` in your repo and the relevant parts of `test.sh` script.

Comment: Not sure if this is your issue, but it seems highly related: Look for issue #2414 of the `actions/runner` repository in GitHub. I got there when I noticed that my `vars` were not quite working, and sure enough, I could confirm it.